# Список пользователей имеющих доступ к базе данных

Tags: mysql

*Ситуация* : на сервере mysql имеется несколько пользователей (все они лежат в таблице mysql.user) и имеется n количество баз данных.
*Вопрос*: как вывести список пользователей имеющих доступ к какой либо конкретной базе данных?
 Например хочу получить список пользователей имеющих разрешение на чтение data_base_one.
как это сделать одним запросом?